# Azure Data Factory Copy Data Error code 2054 Failed to decrypt sub-resource 'None' payload on cloud with error

Tags: encryption, copy

I am trying to copy a csv file from data lake gen v2 to SQL db.
Preview data works on the source link.
But debug failed with error below. Cannot find any reference in the web.

Please advise.

Error code
2054
Troubleshooting guide
Failure type
User configuration issue
Details
Failed to decrypt sub-resource 'None' payload on cloud with error: Failed to decrypt sub-resource payload { "properties": { "annotations": [], "type": "AzureSqlDatabase", "connectVia": { "referenceName": "myintegrationRuntime", "type": "IntegrationRuntimeReference" }, "typeProperties": { "connectionString": "********************", "encryptedCredential": "********************" } }, "name": "AzureSqlDatabase1" } and error is: Cloud stored credentials cannot be found with retry, please check whether related resource had been deleted before. Value is: { "Version": "2017-11-30", "ProtectionMode": "Key", "SecretContentType": "Plaintext", "CredentialId": "CSHFPOC_97157fbc-4813-4e5f-8c2a-a6769bb0f56e" }, type is Plaintext and credentialId is CSHFPOC_97157fbc-4813-4e5f-8c2a-a6769bb0f56e.., status code: BadRequest.